# Async tcp client not receiving data correctly from server

Tags: c#, php, python, sockets, tcp

Im building a multi client to server system using .Net for the client side and python for server side. Currently my python server socket simply echoes back the data sent to it without doing any extra processing:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor, protocol


class Echo(protocol.Protocol):
    """This is just about the simplest possible protocol"""

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        "As soon as any data is received, write it back."
        self.transport.write(data)
        print(str(data))


  def main():
     """This runs the protocol on port 8000"""
     factory = protocol.ServerFactory()
     factory.protocol = Echo
     reactor.listenTCP(8000,factory)
     reactor.run()

 # this only runs if the module was *not* imported
 if __name__ == '__main__':
     main()
```

Its built on the Twisted framework, and can be found on the examples page, at their website.

Im also using the Async TCP client for C# provided by MicroSoft found at:
    https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

The problem is, the client sends the data successfully to the server - and the server receives it, and can echo it successfully, however the line:

```
 self.transport.write(data)
```

Doesnt seem to send the data back correctly because the client never receives a reply back. Why is this happening? Is it a possible deadlock between reading streams?

Comment: Is there any error message at the client, or does it sit there silent? Have you tried connecting with telnet as a client (because whatever you type should be echoed) - what were the results?

Comment: When i run "Telnet 192.168.xx.xx" on my server to ping the machine the client is running on, the telnet attempt times out after about 30 seconds. To top it off, the Client sits there  in the SendCallBack loop im assuming, since the last thing to be printed to console was ""Sent {0} bytes to server."

Comment: With telnet, connect to port 8000 or whatever port your server is running on - so you can manually test the echo

Comment: Telnet connects to the server using telnet 192.168.xx.xx 8000 and simply says connected. It doesnt send or receive any data back from the server though

Comment: Once telnet is connected, you type into telnet, press return. You should see an echo as your server receives and echoes. Also add debugging statements in the python server, see what is going on...